# Android Studio Artic Fox - Device File Explorer missing after every AS restart

Tags: android, android-studio

After recent update of Android Studio to Artic Fox release I noticed that Device File Explorer is missing at SideBar everytime I restart Android Studio.
I have to go to Menu-View-Tool Windows and enable it. But next morning - gone again..
Any hint ?

Comment: It's happening to me as well, probably a bug on their part; I usually double-press the shift key and type in device file explorer, or dfe for short, a bit of a shortcut/workaround if it can't be fixed anytime soon and you need it often

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with laters AS update. ... this is too short to publish